# How do I get full Win32 path from 8.3 DOS path with Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, dos

My question basically says it all.  I am getting this:

```
C:\DOCUME~1\frew\MYDOCU~1\Code\AIRCRA~1\lib\ACD\VALIDA~1.PM
```

and I want this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\frew\My Documents\Code\aircraft_ducting\lib\ACD\Validators.pm
```

I looked at File::Spec::Win32 but that didn't seem to have anything that would do the trick.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Win32::GetLongPathName($path)`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32/Win32.pm#Win32::GetLongPathName%28PATHNAME%29) from the `Win32` module.

Answer (score 7):

[`Win32::GetLongPathName()`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-0.39/Win32.pm#Win32::GetLongPathName%28PATHNAME%29) is all you need.