# Is it possible to access the GetLongPathName() Win32 API in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I need to convert paths in 8.3 convention to full path.
In Perl, I can use [`Win32::GetLongPathName()`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32#Win32%3a%3aGetLongPathName%28PATHNAME%29) as pointed out in [How do I get full Win32 path from 8.3 DOS path with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770171/how-do-i-get-full-win32-path-from-8-3-dos-path-with-perl) But, I need to do it in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ctypes` which is available in the Python standard without the need of using the [pywin32 API](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetShortPathName_meth.html). Like this:

```
from ctypes import *

buf = create_unicode_buffer(260)
GetLongPathName = windll.kernel32.GetLongPathNameW
rv = GetLongPathName(path, buf, 260)
print buf.value
```

From http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-January/006642.html

Comment: It doesn't work.. I tried for path "C:\\progra~1".
Empty string returned.

Comment: I say even more. It returns empty string for long path "C:\\Program Files" too

Comment: I think this does not work for non-unicode string. Use unicode(path) to fix the problem

Answer (score 5):

Use the `GetLongPathName` function from [`win32file`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32file__GetLongPathName_meth.html)

```
import win32file
print win32file.GetLongPathName(r'C:\progra~1')
```

outputs:

```
C:\Program Files
```