# How to get long file system path from python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, path

This returns me a short path (DOS convention) (on Windows):

```
import tempfile
tempDir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
print tempDir

Output >>> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpf76unv
```

Notice the `admini~1`.

How can I get/convert this to a full path? e.g. C:\users\administrator\appdata...

Comment: @Levon I tried a bunch of methods in `os.path` but nothing was doing it for me.

Comment: @AndyArismendi why do you need the full path?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary for my purposes i'm troubleshooting a third party module and wanted to throw full paths at it but didn't find "built-in" way to get the long path, though I could some other reasons one might want this: 1) displaying paths, 2) when [Windows 8.3 Name Creation is disabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try the following code (updated):

```
from ctypes import create_unicode_buffer, windll
BUFFER_SIZE = 500
buffer = create_unicode_buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
get_long_path_name = windll.kernel32.GetLongPathNameW
get_long_path_name(unicode(short_path_name), buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)
long_path_name = buffer.value
```

Hope this helps. Please refer to http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-January/006642.html

Comment: Possible answer is also available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587816/is-it-possible-to-access-the-getlongpathname-win32-api-in-python

Answer (score 9):

```
tempDir = win32file.GetLongPathName(tempDir)
```