# Pathname too long to open?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

This is a screenshot of the execution:

[image]

As you see, the error says that the directory "JSONFiles/Apartment/Rent/dubizzleabudhabiproperty" is not there.

But look at my files, please:

[image]

The folder is definitely there.

#### Update 2

The code

```
self.file = open("JSONFiles/"+ item["category"]+"/" + item["action"]+"/"+ item['source']+"/"+fileName + '.json', 'wb') # Create a new JSON file with the name = fileName parameter
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) # Change the item to a JSON format in one line
        self.file.write(line) # Write the item to the file
```

#### UPDATE

When I change the file name to a smaller one, it works, so the problem is because of the length of the path. what is the solution please?

Comment: Is the file in the folder? With the exact same name?

Comment: @pp_ no the folder is empty, and the "w" option creates the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, this is the source of your problem - the missing file

Comment: You have to create the file before you access it.

Comment: @ForceBru i don't think so because the code works on my mac os, and what i want is to actually create the file, what do you suggest please ?

Comment: @pp the same comment for you please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli , you said some option creates this file. Maybe try to use it?

Comment: @ForceBru i already did, which is adding the `wb` option. as you can see the code in the screenshot

Comment: Do all the directories in the path exist relative to the current directory?

Comment: @cdarke yes diffenately because when i run my code with different parameters, it works and it writes the files, just this file not working

Comment: Please use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create paths when working with windows.

Comment: You might have either a "special" character in the filename, or it could be too long.

Comment: Show the result of `os.path.exists(path)`; I doubt the OS and interpreter are lying to you.

Comment: @msw where should I execute that command please? on which directory ? and what is the value of the path please ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli you give proper path in windows like this C:\\directory1\directory2

Comment: @Lafexlos do you mean instead of `open` ?

Comment: Instead of string concatenation _inside of_ open.

Comment: @cdarke you are amazing, read my new update please

Comment: @Lafexlos the problem is the length of the path, please read my update

Comment: The path length limits depend on the filesystem and version of the OS in use.  It used to be 260 characters (full path, not just one one component) on Windows, but I believe it is much larger now that Unicode filenames are supported.

Comment: I'm not amazing, it was a guess.

Comment: @cdarke any suggestion for the solution please?

Comment: Don't try to store data in a filename?  Looks like you are repeating the folder name in the filename, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @cdarke I didn't get you, but the file name here is a UUID5 just to be sure it is unique, you got me please ? (and i have to make it UUID5 for another process which reads that files and inserts to ElasticSearch, so the id must be unique)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli check this answer help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/python-open-method-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @SRK that answer talks about if you didn't find the file create it, and my problem is IN creating the file, because the file path is long, when i reduce the name of the file, it works perfectly, but with that length, it doesn't work, any suggestion please ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli windows os version and type please  64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: @SRK windows server 2012 r2

Comment: An extended path that starts with ``\\?\`` must be unicode, fully qualified, and only use backslash as the path separator because it gets passed directly to the kernel (the only change made is to replace ``\\?\`` with NT's DOS devices prefix ``\??\``). The maximum extended path length is 32760 characters. A individual file or directory name can be up to 255 characters (127 for the UDF filesystem).

Comment: For example: `path = u"\\\\?\\" + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(u"JSONFiles", item["category"], item["action"], item["source"], fileName + ".json"))`

Comment: @eryksun that is the tick, the **unicode** you added, kindly write an answer to accept it

Answer (score 51):

Regular DOS paths are limited to `MAX_PATH` (260) characters, including the string's terminating `NUL` character. You can exceed this limit by using an extended-length path that starts with the `\\?\` prefix. This path must be a Unicode string, fully qualified, and only use backslash as the path separator. Per Microsoft's [file system functionality comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681827), the maximum extended path length is 32760 characters. A individual file or directory name can be up to 255 characters (127 for the UDF filesystem). Extended UNC paths are also supported as `\\?\UNC\server\share`.

For example:

```python
import os

def winapi_path(dos_path, encoding=None):
    if (not isinstance(dos_path, unicode) and 
        encoding is not None):
        dos_path = dos_path.decode(encoding)
    path = os.path.abspath(dos_path)
    if path.startswith(u"\\\\"):
        return u"\\\\?\\UNC\\" + path[2:]
    return u"\\\\?\\" + path

path = winapi_path(os.path.join(u"JSONFiles", 
                                item["category"],
                                item["action"], 
                                item["source"], 
                                fileName + ".json"))
```

```python
>>> path = winapi_path("C:\\Temp\\test.txt")
>>> print path
\\?\C:\Temp\test.txt
```

See the following pages on MSDN:

- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247)
- [Defining an MS-DOS Device Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363908)
- [Kernel object namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382954)

---

### Background

Windows calls the NT runtime library function `RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus` to convert a DOS path to a native NT path. If we `open` (i.e. `CreateFile`) the above path with a breakpoint set on the latter function, we can see how it handles a path that starts with the `\\?\` prefix.

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus:
00007ff9`d1fb5880 4883ec58        sub     rsp,58h
0:000> du @rcx
000000b4`52fc0f60  "\\?\C:\Temp\test.txt"
0:000> r rdx
rdx=000000b450f9ec18
0:000> pt
ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus+0x66:
00007ff9`d1fb58e6 c3              ret
```

The result replaces `\\?\` with the NT DOS devices prefix `\??\`, and copies the string into a native [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564879):

```
0:000> dS b450f9ec18
000000b4`536b7de0  "\??\C:\Temp\test.txt"
```

If you use `//?/` instead of `\\?\`, then the path is still limited to `MAX_PATH` characters. If it's too long, then `RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName` returns the status code `STATUS_NAME_TOO_LONG` (0xC0000106).

If you use `\\?\` for the prefix but use slash in the rest of the path, Windows *will not* translate the slash to backslash for you:

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus:
00007ff9`d1fb5880 4883ec58        sub     rsp,58h
0:000> du @rcx
0000005b`c2ffbf30  "\\?\C:/Temp/test.txt"
0:000> r rdx
rdx=0000005bc0b3f068
0:000> pt
ntdll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus+0x66:
00007ff9`d1fb58e6 c3              ret
0:000> dS 5bc0b3f068
0000005b`c3066d30  "\??\C:/Temp/test.txt"
```

Forward slash is a valid object name character in the NT namespace. It's reserved by Microsoft filesystems, but you can use a forward slash in other named kernel objects, which get stored in `\BaseNamedObjects` or `\Sessions\[session number]\BaseNamedObjects`. Also, I don't think the I/O manager enforces the policy on reserved characters in device and filenames. It's up to the device. Maybe someone out there has a Windows device that implements a namespace that allows forward slash in names. At the very least you can create DOS device names that contain a forward slash. For example:

```python
>>> kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
>>> kernel32.DefineDosDeviceW(0, u'My/Device', u'C:\\Temp')
>>> os.path.exists(u'\\\\?\\My/Device\\test.txt')
True
```

You may be wondering what `\??` signifies. This used to be an actual directory for DOS device links in the object namespace, but starting with NT 5 (or NT 4 w/ Terminal Services) this became a virtual prefix. The object manager handles this prefix by first checking the logon session's DOS device links in the directory `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\[LOGON_SESSION_ID]` and then checking the system-wide DOS device links in the `\Global??` directory.

Note that the former is a logon session, not a Windows session. The logon session directories are all under the `DosDevices` directory of Windows session 0 (i.e. the services session in Vista+). Thus if you have a mapped drive for a non-elevated logon, you'll discover that it's not available in an elevated command prompt, because your elevated token is actually for a different logon session.

An example of a DOS device link is `\Global??\C:` => `\Device\HarddiskVolume2`. In this case the DOS `C:` drive is actually a symbolic link to the `HarddiskVolume2` device.

Here's a brief overview of how the system handles parsing a path to open a file. Given we're calling WinAPI `CreateFile`, it stores the translated NT `UNICODE_STRING` in an [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749) structure and calls the system function `NtCreateFile`.

```
0:000> g
Breakpoint 1 hit
ntdll!NtCreateFile:
00007ff9`d2023d70 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
0:000> !obja @r8
Obja +000000b450f9ec58 at 000000b450f9ec58:
        Name is \??\C:\Temp\test.txt
        OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE
```

`NtCreateFile` calls the I/O manager function [`IoCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548418), which in turn calls the undocumented object manager API `ObOpenObjectByName`. This does the work of parsing the path. The object manager starts with `\??\C:\Temp\test.txt`. Then it replaces that with `\Global??\C:Temp\test.txt`. Next it parses up to the `C:` symbolic link and has to start over (reparse) the final path `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Temp\test.txt`.

Once the object manager gets to the `HarddiskVolume2` device object, parsing is handed off to the I/O manager, which implements the `Device` object type. The `ParseProcedure` of an I/O `Device` creates the `File` object and an [I/O Request Packet (IRP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550694) with the [major function code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550710) `IRP_MJ_CREATE` (an open/create operation) to be processed by the device stack. This is sent to the device driver via [`IoCallDriver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548336). If the device implements reparse points (e.g. junction mountpoints, symbolic links, etc) and the path contains a reparse point, then the resolved path has to be resubmitted to the object manager to be parsed from the start.

The device driver will use the `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` (almost always present and enabled) of the process token (or thread if impersonating) to bypass access checks while traversing directories. However, ultimately access to the device and target file has to be allowed by a security descriptor, which is verified via [`SeAccessCheck`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563674). Except simple filesystems such as FAT32 don't support file security.

Answer (score 19):

below is Python 3 version regarding @Eryk Sun's solution.

```
def winapi_path(dos_path, encoding=None):
    if (not isinstance(dos_path, str) and encoding is not None): 
        dos_path = dos_path.decode(encoding)
    path = os.path.abspath(dos_path)
    if path.startswith(u"\\\\"):
        return u"\\\\?\\UNC\\" + path[2:]
    return u"\\\\?\\" + path
```

#Python 3 renamed the unicode type to str, the old str type has been replaced by bytes. [NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined - in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution didn't work in my case. I also have a path longer than 259 characters and Python3 in MSYS (www.msys2.org) gives me the "No such file or directory" error. But it works when I run the same python script in Ubuntu under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Answer (score 3):

Adding the solution that helped me fix a similar issue:
python version = 3.9, windows version = 10 pro.

I had an issue with the filename itself as it was too long for python's open built-in method. The error I got is that the path simply doesn't exist, although I use the 'w+' mode for open (which is supposed to open a new file regardless whether it exists or not).

I found this [guide](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-fix-filename-is-too-long-issue-in-windows/) which solved the problem with a quick change to window's Registry Editor (specifically the Group Policy). Scroll down to the 'Make Windows 10 Accept Long File Paths' headline.

Don't forget to update your OS group policy to take effect immediately, a guide can be found [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/group-policy-update-force-windows/).

Hope this helps future searches as this post is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for you getting this error. Please make sure of the following:

1. The parent directory of the folder (JSONFiles) is the same as the directory of the Python script.
2. Even though the folder exists it does not mean the individual file does. Verify the same and make sure the exact file name matches the one that your Python code is trying to access.

If you still face an issue, share the result of "dir" command on the innermost folder you are trying to access.

Comment: regarding your first note, yes i am sure of it. regarding you second note, there is no file with the same name inside that folder, my script **should create that file**. regarding `dir` command, kindly tell me what the script that you want, and i will execute and tell you the results

Comment: As you shared the code, I would suggest you to use os.path.join() command to join the different path variables that you are currently concatenating in the open function and then you can verify the path using os.path.exists().

Comment: please check my new update, it is about the length of the path

Comment: The path names are usually limited to 260 char, but you can extend it to about 32k by using the magic prefix '\\?\'. For further details consult this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maximum%5Fpath%5Flength

Comment: so how should my path look please?

Comment: Your path would be of the following form:- "\\?\veryLongPath"

Comment: I made my path like `"\\?\JSONFiles/` but i got error that  `\\?\\bla bra` does't exist, **notice the extra \ please**

Comment: Try using this:-  path = "\\\\?\\" + os.path.normpath(path)

Comment: longPath = "JSONFiles/"+ item["category"]+"/" + item["action"]+"/"+ item['source']+"/"+fileName + '.json'
        import os
        longPath = "\\\\?\\" + os.path.normpath(longPath) 
        self.file = open(longPath, 'wb')

Comment: that code brings me error "no such file or directly" `\\\\?\\bla bra bla`

Comment: I will go for one hour and come back, i really appreciate you help, i hope we find a solution

Comment: You would have to use absolute paths. Relative paths dont work. Try again and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```py
import os
str1=r"C:\Users\sandeepmkwana\Desktop\folder_structure\models\manual\demodfadsfljdskfjslkdsjfklaj\inner-2djfklsdfjsdklfj\inner3fadsfksdfjdklsfjksdgjl\inner4dfhasdjfhsdjfskfklsjdkjfleioreirueewdsfksdmv\anotherInnerfolder4aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\5qbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccsssssssssssssssss\tmp.txt"
print(len(str1)) #346

path = os.path.abspath(str1)

if path.startswith(u"\\\\"):
    path=u"\\\\?\\UNC\\"+path[2:]
else:
    path=u"\\\\?\\"+path

with open(path,"r+") as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

If you get a long path (more than 258 characters) issue in Windows, then try this.