# Python Zipfile extractall IOError on Windows when extracting files from long paths

Tags: python, windows-7, python-zipfile

I'm running python zipfile extractall, its extracting to a path which is longer than 255 characters. Running this on windows 7 64bit.
I'm getting to following error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'`

Any ideas ?

Its a network folder i want to extract from/to. So I mounted the folder as a network drive t:\ this solved the issue for the time being.

Comment: Make sure that the file exists, first of all. And second, try `import os; os.getcwd()` and make sure the path that it gives you is the directory where the file in question exists.

Comment: the file exists, if i run it with the workaround mentioned above it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
class ZipfileLongPaths(zipfile.ZipFile):

    def _extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd):
        targetpath = winapi_path(targetpath)
        return zipfile.ZipFile._extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd)
```

Where winapi_path is:

```
def winapi_path(dos_path, encoding=None):
    path = os.path.abspath(dos_path)

    if path.startswith("\\\\"):
        path = "\\\\?\\UNC\\" + path[2:]
    else:
        path = "\\\\?\\" + path 

    return path
```

winapi_path taken from [pathname too long to open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219317/pathname-too-long-to-open/36237176)