# Open file with very long path

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to open multiple files on Windows 10 with PIL. 
Each of these files have a very long hash combinations as their name. 
Storing them directly in:

`C:\\Users\\my-user-name\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\.........`

works, but as soon as I place them in one additional sub level, e.g.:

`C:\\Users\\my-user-name\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\sub-folder\\.........`

it is no longer possible to open them because the string becomes to long.

According to [Long paths in Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557760/long-paths-in-python-on-windows) I tried to add \?\ in front of the path, e.g.:

`f = '\\?\C:\\Users\\my-user-name\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\sub-folder\\...'
Image.open(f)`

but unfortunately it does not work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558658/7546950) on a similar issue:

Comment: Well It appears I messed up the \\?\ in front of my path string, it worked by using
`extended_path = "\\\\?\\%s" % d` and then `Image.open(extended_path)`

Comment: FYI You can use Python's "raw" strings to prevent any backslash-escape sequences to be changed, which can make stuff like this (and regular expressions) a bit more readable. E.g. `r"\?\C:\Users\my-user...."`.

Comment: Use `r"..."` - raw string doesn't need escaping, you'll only need to use backslashes once.

Comment: @TomDalton, the string needs to be Unicode in order to support extended paths prior to Windows 8 (the system's ANSI -> Unicode decoding used to use a static `MAX_PATH` buffer) and also because a Windows filepath should be Unicode anyway. This means *in Python 2 we cannot use a raw string* since they're broken for `unicode` string literals. In Python 2 we need `f = u'\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\...'`.

Comment: In that case my other suggestion is not to use Python 2 ;-)