# Cannot Create Long Filename on Windows 10 & Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, python-3.6

On Windows 10 Home and Python 3.6.6, I have enabled long paths by [setting it in the registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) and by [prefixing `\\?\`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation). I have also followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105517/5305519) and ensured that the path uses `\\` instead of `/`, is in unicode `u'` and is an absolute path. There are no illegal characters in my file name. My file path is also way smaller than the [maximum total path length of 32,767 characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation).

Despite doing all of the above, I still get `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` when I try to create a long file name. I have tried 3 different ways of creating the filepath as `output_filepath` below but all do not work:

```py
# Long filename - Does not work
import os, pathlib
output_filepath = u'\\\\?\\' + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), u"somereallylongname" * 30 + u".result")
# output_filepath = u'\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Jarrett\\Downloads\\somereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongname\\x.x'
# output_filepath = r'\\?\C:\Users\Jarrett\Downloads\somereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongname\x.x'
print("filepath length = %s" % len(output_filepath))
print("filename length = %s" % len(os.path.basename(output_filepath)))
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(output_filepath)): os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_filepath))
pathlib.Path(output_filepath).touch() # or open(output_filepath, 'a').close()
print("Wrote to " + output_filepath)
```

Comment: Strings in Python 3 are unicode; there's no need to use the `u` prefix from Python 2. Also, if you're using Python 3.6+ and Windows 10, and you've enabled long paths in the registry, then you do not need to use an extended path (i.e. non-normalized device path) in the "\\?\" device root path. You can use regular DOS paths. The problem, as discussed below by Drake, is that the filesystem's maximum component length is fixed per its internal data structures, and absolutely nothing can change that.

Comment: The Windows API itself has a similar component length limit baked into the result of a directory listing from `FindFirstFileW` / `FindNextFileW`, as called internally by Python's `os.listdir` and `os.scandir`. The API limits names in a directory listing to `MAX_PATH` (260) characters. Note that in this case they've reused the `MAX_PATH` constant, though the names in a directory listing are not paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name component (the part between the backslashes in the file name) is too long, the Max number of Component Length depends on the value returned in the `lpMaximumComponentLength` parameter of the [`GetVolumeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa) function.

For example, for a FAT file system that supports long names, the function stores the value 255.

Try to shorten the length of the file name component, like:

```
import os, pathlib
output_filepath = u'\\\\?\\' + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), u"somereallylongname" * 14 + u'\\' + u"somereallylongname" * 14 + u'\\' + u"somereallylongname" * 2 + u".result")
# output_filepath = u'\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Jarrett\\Downloads\\somereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongname\\x.x'
# output_filepath = r'\\?\C:\Users\Jarrett\Downloads\somereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongnamesomereallylongname\x.x'
print(output_filepath)
print("filepath length = %s" % len(output_filepath))
print("filename length = %s" % len(os.path.basename(output_filepath)))
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(output_filepath)): os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_filepath))
pathlib.Path(output_filepath).touch() # or open(output_filepath, 'a').close()
print("Wrote to " + output_filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In other words what you are saying is that filepath can be >255 but filename cannot, thus the error?

Comment: Yes, according to the last document you linked, "*...permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the `lpMaximumComponentLength` parameter of the [`GetVolumeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa) function (this value is commonly 255 characters). ...*"

Comment: "*but filename cannot*", and the directory name between backslashes.

Comment: Hi, @jarrettyeo does this answer your question?