# Python os.getcwd() returns with tilde in the path. e.g. C:\MYFOLD~1\test

Tags: python, path, directory, tilde, getcwd

How can I get python to return the full pathname of C:\myfolderisafolder\test?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587816/is-it-possible-to-access-the-getlongpathname-win32-api-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
E:\dev>cd VARESE~1

E:\dev\VARESE~1>python
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'E:\\dev\\VARESE~1'
>>> exit()

E:\dev\VARESE~1>cd ..
E:\dev>cd VAResearchDemo

E:\dev\VAResearchDemo>python
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'E:\\dev\\VAResearchDemo'
>>> exit()
```

As you can see, if I run `python` in `VARESE~1` directory, `os.getcwd()` returns short path. If I run `python` in same directory but with long path, it returns long path.

So, you should try to run `python` in `C:\myfolderisafolder\test` (check link's properties or how you run it).

But if you need to *convert* a short path to a long path, you have to call win32's `GetLongPathName` function

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `os.path.realpath`, `os.path.normpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help:

```
fullpath = os.path.expanduser('~/my/path')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string with .split() at the tilde and then rejoin the full filepath with the .join() methods.